# The FabricJS selection box is shifted when the canvas is transformed

Tags: javascript, canvas, customization, fabricjs

I am using FabricJS and I am trying to have two canvases next to each other which behave like one. So I can drag objects between them.
My idea was to shift the viewport of the second canvas about the size of the first and then add the same objects to both of the canvases. 
Here you can see what I did so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/ytdzo38h/

The selection box for the object is now shifted and therefore the object can't be grabbed in both canvases.
I found out that `canvas.wrapperEl.getBoundingClientRect()`gives back the coordinates of the selection box, but I have no idea how I could adjust that to fit my needs. I would really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Do you need to drag object between two canvas?

Comment: Yes, that would be the best :)